# What can I modify in my JavaFX GUI that will display the output correctly? It displays the tips for integers only

Tags: java, javafx

I am a beginner currently learning JavaFX in my college programming class. I am designing a tip calculator, but I cannot get it to display the tip and check information if the starting check amount is a double. How can I modify my code to display the correct outputs? Would it be an issue with my Lambda expression?

```
// declare interface controls

Label titleLabel, checkAmtLabel, tipPercentLabel, splitLabel, tipAmtLabel;
Label totalLabel, amtPerPersonLabel;

TextField checkAmtText, tipAmtText, totalText, amtPerPersonText;

Slider tipPercentSlider;

ChoiceBox splitChoiceBox;

Button calcTipButton;

// declare a grid pane (8 rows and 2 columns)
GridPane grid;


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    // instantiate labels and their properties
    titleLabel = new Label("Tip Calculator");
    titleLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    titleLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    checkAmtLabel = new Label("Check Amount");
    checkAmtLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    checkAmtLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    tipPercentLabel = new Label("Tip Percent: ");
    tipPercentLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    tipPercentLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    splitLabel = new Label("Split");
    splitLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    splitLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    tipAmtLabel = new Label("Tip Amount");
    tipAmtLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    tipAmtLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    totalLabel = new Label("Total");
    totalLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    totalLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    amtPerPersonLabel = new Label("Amount Per Person");
    amtPerPersonLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    amtPerPersonLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

    // instantiate text fileds and their properties
    checkAmtText = new TextField();
    tipAmtText = new TextField();
    tipAmtText.setEditable(false);
    totalText = new TextField();
    totalText.setEditable(false);
    amtPerPersonText = new TextField();
    amtPerPersonText.setEditable(false);
    //checkAmtText.setOnMouseClick(e -> clearClick());

    // instantiate a slider and its properties 
    tipPercentSlider = new Slider();
    tipPercentSlider.setPrefWidth(300);
    tipPercentSlider.setMin(0);
    tipPercentSlider.setMax(25);
    tipPercentSlider.setMajorTickUnit(5);
    tipPercentSlider.setMinorTickCount(0);
    tipPercentSlider.setBlockIncrement(5);
    tipPercentSlider.setShowTickLabels(true);
    tipPercentSlider.setShowTickMarks(true);
    tipPercentSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
    tipPercentSlider.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    tipPercentSlider.valueProperty().addListener(
            (observable, oldvalue, newvalue) ->
                    {
                // show integer values only
            tipPercentLabel.setText(String.format("Tip Percent: %2d%s",newvalue.intValue(),"%"));
    } );

    // instantiate a choice box and its properties
    splitChoiceBox = new ChoiceBox();
        splitChoiceBox.getItems().addAll("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
        splitChoiceBox.setValue("1");

    // instantiate a button and its properties
    calcTipButton = new Button("Calculate Tip");
    calcTipButton.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    calcTipButton.setOnAction(e -> calcTipClick());


    // instantiate a grid pane and its properties
    grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setHgap(15);
    grid.setVgap(15);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    grid.add(titleLabel, 0, 0, 2, 1);
    grid.addRow(1, checkAmtLabel, checkAmtText);
    grid.addRow(2, tipPercentLabel, tipPercentSlider);
    grid.addRow(3, splitLabel, splitChoiceBox);
    grid.add(calcTipButton, 0, 4, 2, 1);
    grid.addRow(5, tipAmtLabel, tipAmtText);
    grid.addRow(6, totalLabel, totalText);
    grid.addRow(7, amtPerPersonLabel, amtPerPersonText);

    // instantiate the grid pane and put items in in grid

   Scene scene = new Scene(grid);
   scene.getRoot().setStyle("-fx-font: 15 'Comic Sans MS'"); 

   primaryStage.setTitle("Tip Calculator");
   primaryStage.setScene(scene);
   primaryStage.show();

}

private void calcTipClick() {      
    //Gather choiceBox
    String choiceInput = splitChoiceBox.getValue().toString();
    int choiceSelection = Integer.parseInt(choiceInput.substring(0, 1));

    //Gather Slider information
    Number sliderInput = tipPercentSlider.getValue();

    //Gather textField amount
    String val = checkAmtText.getText();
    //I Used a string converter in this part
    NumberStringConverter nsc = new NumberStringConverter();
    Number amount = 0;

    Number tipAmount = amount.doubleValue() * sliderInput.doubleValue()/100;
    tipAmtText.setText(tipAmount.toString());

    Number totalAmount = tipAmount.doubleValue() + amount.doubleValue();
    totalText.setText(totalAmount.toString());

    Number perPerson = totalAmount.doubleValue() / choiceSelection;
    amtPerPersonText.setText(perPerson.toString());
}
```

Comment: Hi Alec, there is way to much code.  Shortcut it.  Read this for tips on how to post a good question, that will attract more people to help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.   You should highlight the problem area and remove the rest.  Something we can replicate locally is prefect to try on our side.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Start by using generics with the `ChoiceBox`:

```
ChoiceBox<Integer> = new ChoiceBox<>();
// ...
splitChoiceBox.getItems().addAll(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
splitChoiceBox.setValue(1);
```

This ensures type safety and takes care of retrieving the value as an `int`:

```
//Gather choiceBox
int choiceSelection = splitChoiceBox.getValue();
```

Now to your `calcTipClick` method. Why convert `double`s to `Number` and then back to `double`? Just use `double` in first place:

```
//Gather Slider information
double sliderInput = tipPercentSlider.getValue();
//...
double tipAmount = amount * sliderInput / 100;
double totalAmount = tipAmount + amount;
double perPerson = totalAmount / choiceSelection;
```

To convert `double` to `String` Google that and after you found the answer look at the bottom of this one.

To convert `String` to `double` do the same as above.

As to why nothing is displayed in your fields, look again at your code for this method and use a debugger to find out where what you think should be happening isn't happening. It's trivial.

**Note:** Don't use fields when local variables will do (e.g., your labels).

---

`double` to `String`:

> `tipAmtText.setText(String.valueOf(tipAmount));`
>  `totalText.setText(totalAmount + "");` 
>  `amtPerPersonText.setText(Double.toString(perPerson));`

`String` to `double`:

> `Double.parseDouble(val)`
>  `fromString(val)` of your `NumberStringConverter` if you really need to